# What's meant by "a family $\{A_i\}$ of subsets of $X$"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This comes from Analytical Topology by Burgess:

> If with each member $i$ of a non-null set $I$ (not necessarily having members in common with $S$) there is associated a unique subset $X_i$ of $S$, then the collection of sets $X_i$, for $i$ in $I$, forms a **family** of sets, denoted by: $\{X_i\}, i\in I$.

And this comes from page 34 of Naive Set Theory by Halmos:

> Thus, for instance, the phrase "a family $\{A_i\}$ of subsets of $X$" is usually understood to refer to a function $A$, from some set I of indices, into $P(X)$.

I'm really confused, because the first definition appears to refer to more than one subset, the second to just one subset.

Comment: The only real difference is that Halmos doesn't require the sets to be unique. Halmos's function associates to each $i$ a subset $A(i)\subseteq X$ - that is $A(i)\in P(X)$. Burgess just requires $A(i)\neq A(j)$ if $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR,** $A_i$ is just a sequence of subsets in both definitions, but we use the term "family" because we don't really need to think of them as having any kind of order. The definition that Burgess gives is interesting, since he requires that each $A_i$ be unique. I'm not sure I agree with this. I'd still consider $A_1 = A_2 = A_3 = ... = \emptyset$ a family of subsets, but perhaps his definition makes more sense for later parts of the book.

Everything is a function. If you don't think it's a function, you're not thinking functionally enough. Suppose I have a sequence of numbers, $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, let's just say $x_i = i^2$ for concreteness. We can also think of this as a function, $x : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, with $x(i) = i^2$. These two mathematical objects are basically the same thing, just written differently. This is why, in the second definition, $A$ is described as a function.

Let $X$ be the set of all clothes. Let $I$ be the set of all popes. Let $A_i \subseteq X$ for $i \in I$ be the set of all clothes worn by pope $i$. $A_{\text{John Paul II}}, A_{\text{Adrian I}},A_{\text{Boniface VI}}, ...$ forms a family of subsets of $X$, since for each pope we can associate a set of clothes (definition 1), and $A:I \rightarrow P(X)$ is a function mapping the set of popes on to the set of all subsets of the set of clothes (definition 2).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the second refers to more than one subset. It is one function which maps one set of indices to more than one subset of $P(X)$. For example we could take $X = \{2,3\}$ and a set $I = \{0,1,2\}$ of indices, in which case $P(X) = \{\emptyset, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{2,3\}\}$ and our function $A:I\rightarrow P(X)$ could be defined $A(0) = \{2\}$, $A(1) = \{3\}$, $A(2) = \{2,3\}$.

Thomas Andrews' comment at the start is correct: the only difference is that Burgess requires uniqueness.